# Start <ol> with a number

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to start my ol list with a specific number.
My html

```
 <ol start="3">
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
 </ol>
```

but the start is not working. Any idea how can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Its working. http://jsfiddle.net/46m6u/

Comment: True it works, but not in my code! Should be something else that influences it. It is problem if you have many lists on a page?

Comment: show your complete code - @novellino

Comment: sorry but that is difficult. is part of big projec, so the code is big. but I think the relevant part is simple and similar to that.  anyway thats for the help. i will check if something else breaks it.

Comment: what happens in your project? does it start with 1 or are there no numbers at all? Do you maybe have a list-style-type: none and add your own counter with css? Then start doesn't apply

Comment: it starts with 1 yes. the list-style is decimal and I do not have my own css. that is why is it a bit strange

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this code works fine you can check this

```
 <body>
  <ol start="3">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ubdA3/)

Comment: you can visit this link this works fine  http://jsfiddle.net/ubdA3/

Comment: novillo this works fine I checked this code on jsfiddle above is the link to url you can see this;

Comment: how often do you want to mention, that it works? doesn't solve the problem....

Comment: I said before to another comment "Thanks it is true that is works, probably is something else in my code that influences it and I will check that".